# the led of wireless card is always flashing

Tags: arch-linux, network-adapter, led

I just installed archlinux and awesome on my laptop. But I find that the led of wireless card is always flashing in connect status. Is there any way to disable it?

NIC:

07:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection (rev 02)

Comment: Sounds like the device is suppose to connect when its connected.

Comment: Yes, but it is OK in windows. I tried to add a file iwl_blink.conf in /etc/modprobe.d/ and the content is " options iwlcore led_mode=1 " but failed

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution on arch wiki:

For iwl3945, iwl4965 and iwl5000-series

Note: This works with the iwlegacy and iwlwifi drivers.
The default settings on the module are to have the LED blink on activity. Some people find this extremely annoying. To have the LED on solid when Wi-Fi is active, you can use the systemd-tmpfiles:

```
/etc/tmpfiles.d/phy0-led.conf
w /sys/class/leds/phy0-led/trigger - - - - phy0radio
```

Run systemd-tmpfiles --create phy0-led.conf for the change to take effect, or reboot.
To see all the possible trigger values for this LED:

```
# cat /sys/class/leds/phy0-led/trigger
```

Tip: If you do not have /sys/class/leds/phy0-led, you may try to use the led_mode="1" module option. It should be valid for both iwlwifi and iwlegacy drivers.